# Taking an existing type and making each of its properties optional

Tags: typescript

Can I pick a some properties from a type while setting them to `Optional` in the new type?

Existing type:

```js
interface RequiredInfo {
    name: string
    ...
}
```

Desired mapped type:

```
type OptionalInfo = { 
    name?: string
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more information?  See the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  So far this doesn't seem to be a [mcve].  Do you just want `Partial<RequiredInfo>`?  Or `Partial<Pick<RequiredInfo, "name">>`?  Or `Partial<Pick<RequiredInfo, "name">> & Omit<RequiredInfo, "name">`?  ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) in general are able to add modifiers like `readonly` or `?` (optional). Based on this construct, you have a couple of possibilities to make properties optional.

**Make all properties optional with built-in Partial type:**

```
/*
type OptionalInfo = {
  name?: string | undefined;
  foo?: number | undefined;
}
*/
type OptionalInfo = Partial<RequiredInfo>
```

**Pick some optional properties:**

```
/*
type OptionalInfoPick = {
    name?: string | undefined;
} 
*/
type OptionalInfoPick = Pick<Partial<RequiredInfo>, "name">
// or
type OptionalInfoPickAlt = { [K in Extract<keyof RequiredInfo, "name">]?: RequiredInfo[K] }
```

Combine optional and non-optional properties:

```
interface RequiredInfo {
    name: string
    foo: number
}

/*
type Combined = {
    foo: number;
    name?: string | undefined;
}
*/
type Combined = Pick<RequiredInfo, "foo"> & Pick<Partial<RequiredInfo>, "name">
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=92#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI4FdhQgEwEkQYB7ZAbwChlbkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzGusqTYgsjAEbQqAXypUwATwAOKAPKKwwUgwA2xMsgC8yAApwoGuNoA86bLgJ7SAPlkLlyNRq2XHx4AgBrQxN-AKtTc2BLG0wcPCISZwAaZAAiBmZUlzdVdU0dX1CAQW0wYIpkAG0AaWRQZABRAA8uRDArAIh5Uhg0WPsEshT0pggsgF0AfjZbOIdEmvHkGSoAegAqOSUUAGFScVACcv5aQWFRCSgAbhP6UemOLl5kAB9kLBB8CBhD-BuZdarLbuPYHEBHIx+QIxOzxRzDQRZZAAMhC0IiFmsswGjicwwyYycyCAA)

If you happen to name a type for these, I would not call it `Nullable`, as that would suggerate a property with `null` value instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please explain this line to me: type OptionalInfoPickAlt = { [K in Extract<keyof RequiredInfo, "name">]?: RequiredInfo[K] }

Comment: It is just a more verbose form of `Pick<Partial<RequiredInfo>, "name">`. Given `RequiredInfo` would have keys `"foo"` and `"name"`, `Extract<keyof RequiredInfo, "name">` just says, from the union of key types `"foo" | "name"` choose all key constituents that are assignable to "name" - the result would be `"name"`. Several keys can be specified like  `Extract<RequiredInfo, "name" | "foo">`. And the value part `RequiredInfo[K]` means, for each extracted key `K`, let the property value type just be the corresponding value type of `RequiredInfo` for `K`.

Comment: For more infos on `Extract`, have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types).